# React component mounts multiple times and causes problems in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

We are sending some data to Google Analytics in our React application. We are sending them in our custom hook. To prevent sending duplicate values, we introduced a "marker" string which will get the value of whatever is being sent. Every time the hook is called, it will create a new "marker", compare it to the old one and if they are the same, nothing should be sent to GA. Otherwise, it will be sent and the marker will be updated. At least that's how this should work. For some reason the hook fires four times (which is still fine). However, for some other reason the state is not being updated on time, and the equality operator is not able to figure out that the marker strings shouldn't be equal. As the consequence, the same data gets sent to the GA twice. I need to understand why this is happening.

**Note:** *I edited the question and the code to reflect the findings which **@Keith** and **@ramkumar2098** helped me figure out.*

With strategically placed `console.log`s, I noticed that the effect gets called **4 times**. In the first and second iteration, `trackedMarker` is empty and `newMarker` is set correctly, but it looks like `setTrackedMarker(newMarker)` doesn't produce any result on time (I know it's async, but still...). In the third and fourth iteration, both `trackedMarker` and `newMarker` have identical values (which is the correct state to expect after the data is sent to the GA). More details below in the code comments:

**Hook:**

```
export const useGA = (
  someKey: string,
  results: readonly Readonly<OurResultType>[],
): void => {
  const [trackedMarker, setTrackedMarker] = useState('');
  const gtm = useGoogleTagManager();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Effect called!'); // called 4 times for 1 page load
    const newMarker = someKey + results.map((r) => r.id).join(',');

    console.log('Tracked marker: ' + trackedMarker); // Empty in the first and second log iteration
    console.log('New marker:     ' + newMarker); // Has correct value every time

    if (trackedMarker !== newMarker) {
      setTrackedMarker(newMarker);
      gtm.push(...);
      console.log('Pushed!');
    }
    console.log('New tracked marker: ', trackedMarker); // First two times empty, on the third and fourth time has correct value
  }, [someKey, results, trackedMarker, gtm]);
};
```

**Component which is using the hook:**

```
export const OurComponent: React.FC<OurComponentProps> = ({
  someKey,
}) => {
  ...
  useGA(someKey, results);
  ...
}
```

**The component which is using `OurComponent`**:

```
export const SomeUpperComponent: React.FC<SomeUpperComponentProps> = ({
  hasResults,
  someKey,
}) => {
  ...
  return hasResults ? <OurComponent someKey={someKey} /> : <NoResults />;
};
```

Those `console.log`s from the hook output the following:

**1st time:**

```
Effect called!
Tracked marker:
New marker: 9018a12a-6cd1-4020-91ca-a05a3a81f1744,2,5,3,1,8,7,6,9,10
New tracked marker:
Pushed!
```

**2nd time:**

```
Effect called!
Tracked marker:
New marker: 9018a12a-6cd1-4020-91ca-a05a3a81f1744,2,5,3,1,8,7,6,9,10
New tracked marker:
Pushed!
```

**3rd time:**

```
Effect called!
Tracked marker:
New marker: 9018a12a-6cd1-4020-91ca-a05a3a81f1744,2,5,3,1,8,7,6,9,10
New tracked marker: 9018a12a-6cd1-4020-91ca-a05a3a81f1744,2,5,3,1,8,7,6,9,10
```

**4th time:**

```
Effect called!
Tracked marker:
New marker: 9018a12a-6cd1-4020-91ca-a05a3a81f1744,2,5,3,1,8,7,6,9,10
New tracked marker: 9018a12a-6cd1-4020-91ca-a05a3a81f1744,2,5,3,1,8,7,6,9,10
```

So apparently the effect gets called multiple times and that's the core issue. On the second call, the markers are still different, and the push to GA is fired one more time. Initially I thought that JavaScript is acting weird and not able to figure out that two strings are equal but now it looks like that there is some issue with component mounting multiple times for unknown reason and the state not being updated on time...

**Credits:**

As **ramkumar2098** pointed out in the answer, I had an issue with `console.log`s, because I was using "+" instead of "," and it affected the result of the comparison in the log itself.

As **Keith** pointed out in the comments, I should've made sure how many times the component is being mounted and that resulted in the updated question and more detailed description of the issue.

Comment: Have you checked their lengths? There might be some whitespaces which make them inequal?

Comment: Nope, they are exactly the same, I tried adding "<" and ">" just before and after the strings to be 100% sure.

Comment: If you do `useEffect(() = console.log("mount"), [])`. How many times does mount appear?

Comment: @Keith Twice...

Comment: That means it's getting mounted twice, could you check how many times your `useEffect` fires, are you sure it's only twice, and not scrolled up in console?

Comment: Only twice, I double-checked. But exactly that is the reason why we added that "safeguard" condition. And my main concern here is - why does React/JavaScript think that two same strings are not same?

Comment: @Keith I'm sorry for the confusion. Now I checked again with differently placed console.logs and it turns out that the mount is called 4 (four) times! I rephrased the question completely, since now this finding changes everything.

Comment: Do you have [`StrictMode`](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) as it will re-run your Effect an extra time. Your initial render is having `trackedMarker` as empty string so the condition is truthy and `setTrackedMarker` causes re-render and because `useEffect` depends on `trackedMarker` it re-runs again the Effect again. So 2 times in total and 4 times with `StrictMode`. And your log of `trackedMarker` shows the current state and not the updated state, so move it outside `useEffect` but still inside your component's top-level scope

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment saying I can't reproduce the error of 2 same string being not the same (`!==`) and suggested you to remove cache, so is that fixed by now?

Comment: @Aleksandar in `next.config.js` we have `reactStrictMode: true`, I guess that should be it...

Comment: @vtomic85 inside root file (`index.tsx`/`main.tsx`) is your `<App/>` wrapped around `StrictMode`?

Comment: @Aleksandar I can't find it anywhere in the code. In `_app.page.tsx` there are many wrappers, but no `StrictMode`

Comment: @Aleksandar Update: In `next.config.js` when I switch `reactStrictMode` from `true` to `false`, the problem disappears and the data is sent only once to the GA. However, I'm not sure if this is an acceptable solution (I have to check it with the lead engineer but I guess the answer will be "no"). Is there any other approach?

Comment: Sadly for you, with `reactStrictMode`, the `useEffect` will run twice as you can see here: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode
You can't do anything for this extra time except pass it to false

Comment: @OneQ It says "Strict Mode enables the following development-only behaviors", so I guess it won't run twice in production... But then I'm wondering if something else is the issue (since the bug was detected in production environment).

Comment: With your code and the strictmode it should at least run three times. Two for the strictmode and the third one because you set the state and therefore with the dependecy array it runs again. But the fourth time is strange.

Answer (score 2):

Use comma instead of `+` operator in you console logs.

```
console.log('Condition 1:', marker !== newMarker);
console.log('Condition 2:', marker != newMarker);
```

The `+` operator concatenates 'Condition 1: ' and `marker` and comparing that with `newMarker`.

Comment: That solves the problem for the console.log, but not why it doesn't work correctly in the if statement.

Comment: As @Geshode wrote, it did solve the console.log problem (thanks for that), and now I'm even more confused. The equality operator  apparently works properly, the condition is not fulfilled, but still the same thing is pushed twice to the GA... I checked the contents of window.dataLayer in the browser to confirm that. I updated the original question now.

Comment: I rephrased the question after @Keith gave me a hint to check how many times the components gets mounted. Now it looks like the equality operator works just fine (really? :)), but there is an issue with the component being mounted 4 times (!) and the state doesn't get updated on time for the change to be detected.